# How to find if requested time is between timerange in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

I have the date input in the string format (ex:- `2020-01-08T07:00:00`) and i want to check if input time is between `6:00` to `15:00`.
any idea how can i check this?

I have tried below code:-

```
java.util.Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse("2020-01-08T07:00:00");
if(inputDate.getTime() < "06:00" && inputDate.getTime() > "15:00")
```

but it can not compare with String obviously,so i am confused how to compare it?

Comment: Do not use the old Date-Api. use the `java.time`API

Comment: also: "06:00" is a String, not a moment in time

Comment: Parse it to a ZonedDateTime; convert it to a LocalDateTime; get the LocalTime from that; compare that LocalTime to your range.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `LocalTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the good answer from YCF_L.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please avoid using legacy date library, instead I suggest to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) like this :

```
// format your date time by using the default formater of LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-08T07:00:00");

// Get the time part from your LocalDateTime
LocalTime lt = ldt.toLocalTime();

// create a patter to format the two times
DateTimeFormatter hmFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");

// use isAfter and isBefore to check if your date in the range you expect
if (lt.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("6:00", hmFormatter)) && 
        lt.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("15:00", hmFormatter))) {

}
```

Comment: DateTimeFormatter is from org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter , right? it is saying that ofPattern(String) is undefined for the type DateTimeFormatter

Comment: @JavaSSE [it exist](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), yes, but me I refer to java-time [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)